# Why is the mean filter giving totally white output?

Tags: image-processing, filter, mean, convolution

[Here in Accord.net](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/development/Sources/Accord.Imaging/AForge.Imaging/Filters/Convolution/Mean.cs), they used

```
1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1,
```

I am also using the [same here in my code](https://github.com/edurazee/KassWitkinFilterBankReminiscent/blob/master/KassWitkinFilterBankReminiscent/MeanFilter.cs).

```
public partial class Filters
{
     private static double[,] _meanKernel = 
        new double[,] { { 1, 1, 1, }, 
                        { 1, 1, 1, }, 
                        { 1, 1, 1, }, };

     public static Bitmap FftMean(Bitmap image)
     {
         return FftPaddedConvolutionFilter(image, _meanKernel);
     }
}
```

But, I am obtaining totally white output.

**What am I doing incorrectly?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this kernel as it is, you compute the sum of all the pixels in the 8-neighborhood. So I guess that for most of the pixels, the result is greater than 255, and then it is truncated.

If you want to compute the mean, use 1.0/9.0 instead of 1.

Comment: Yes. But how are 'they' using it?

Comment: I guess that they don't use the FFT, and they divide the sum by 9.